# Error al usar taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación android que alimenta una base de datos de Firebase. Lo que pasa es que cada objeto tiene consigo una imagen. Por lo que necesito usar tanto el Firebase Database como el Firebase Storage. El problema esta que al subir el objeto a la base de datos, el resultado del DownloadUrl es el siguiente `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@ccf0d22`.
Mi MainActivity es el siguiente:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etNombre;
    private EditText etDescripcion;
    private EditText etPrecio;
    private EditText etCantidad;
    private ImageButton btnImg;
    private Button btnGuardarProd;
    private String Nombre;
    private String Descripcion;
    private double Precio;
    private int Cantidad;
    private String stPrecio;
    private String stCantidad;
    /*--------------- IMAGE USING DECLARATIONS ------------------*/
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    Uri imageUri;
    private ImageView imgPreview;
    /*--------------- DATABASE USING DECLARATIONS ----------------*/
    private FirebaseDatabase db;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    /*--------------- STORAGE USING DECLARATIONS -----------------*/
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private StorageReference task;
    private String nombrefoto;
  //  private Uri uriBBDD;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*---------- USABLE ELEMENTS DECLARATION ------------------------*/
        etNombre = findViewById(R.id.et_nombreprod);
        etDescripcion = findViewById(R.id.et_descprod);
        etCantidad = findViewById(R.id.et_cantidadprod);
        etPrecio = findViewById(R.id.et_precioprod);
        btnImg = findViewById(R.id.btn_selecImg);
        btnGuardarProd = findViewById(R.id.btnGuardarProd);
        etPrecio.setText("0");
        etCantidad.setText("0");
        /*---------------------------------------------------------------*/

        /*---------------------------- FIREBASE USE START ---------------------------*/
        IniciarFirebase();



        /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        /*---------------------------- SAVE BUTTON FUNCTION -------------------------*/
        btnGuardarProd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Nombre = etNombre.getText().toString();
                Descripcion = etDescripcion.getText().toString();
                stPrecio = etPrecio.getText().toString();
                Precio = Double.parseDouble(stPrecio);
                stCantidad = etCantidad.getText().toString();
                Cantidad = Integer.parseInt(stCantidad);



                if(Nombre.equals("")||Descripcion.equals("")||Precio==0||Cantidad==0|| imageUri==null){

                    validacion();
                }
                else {

                    SubirProducto();
                    LimpiarCajas();


                }

            }
        });
        /*-------------------- GET AN IMAGE FROM THE DEVICE GALLERY -----------------*/
        imgPreview = findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
        btnImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery();
            }
        });


    }

    private void SubirProducto() {
        StorageReference FilePath = mStorage.child("Fotos").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());

        FilePath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                nombrefoto= taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                Producto p = new Producto();
                p.setPid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                p.setNombre(Nombre);
                p.setDescripcion(Descripcion);
                p.setCantidad(Cantidad);
                p.setPrecio(Precio);
                p.setReferencia(nombrefoto);
                 reference.child("Producto").child(p.getPid()).setValue(p);
            }
        });


    }

    private void IniciarFirebase() {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        db = db.getInstance();
        reference = db.getReference();
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    }

    private void LimpiarCajas() {
        etCantidad.setText("0");
        etPrecio.setText("0");
        etDescripcion.setText("");
        etNombre.setText("");
        imageUri=null;
        imgPreview.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }

    private void validacion() {
        if(Nombre.equals("")){
            etNombre.setError("Obligatorio");
        }
        if(Descripcion.equals("")){
            etDescripcion.setError("Obligatorio");
        }
        if(stPrecio.equals("0")){
            etPrecio.setError("Obligatorio");
        }
        if(stCantidad.equals("0")){
            etCantidad.setError("Obligatorio");
        }
        if(imageUri==null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Completa el formulario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
        }
    }

    private void openGallery() {
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Foto adquirida con exito su Uri es: " + imageUri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            imgPreview.setImageURI(imageUri);
            //btnImg.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }

    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
}
```

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda. Llevo ya peleandome tiempo con esto. Necesito conseguir bien el DownloadUrl() para que a la hora de recoger los datos de la base de datos, pueda descargar y unir de manera correcta las imagenes a sus productos.
Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: Si para probarlo necesitais algo mas como la clase del objeto o el layout decirme y lo subo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO!!!
Tras un rato probando distintas cosas esta ha sido la solución que he encontrado para poder guardar en un objeto de la Database el enlace de descarga del Storage de Firebase.

```
  private void SubirProducto() {
    final StorageReference FilePath = mStorage.child("Fotos").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());


    FilePath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


          FilePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    uriBBDD=uri;
                    guardarProducto(uriBBDD);
                }
            });
          
        }
    });


}

private void guardarProducto(Uri uri) {
    nombrefoto=uri.toString();
    Producto p = new Producto();
    p.setPid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    p.setNombre(Nombre);
    p.setDescripcion(Descripcion);
    p.setCantidad(Cantidad);
    p.setPrecio(Precio);
    p.setReferencia(nombrefoto);
    reference.child("Producto").child(p.getPid()).setValue(p);
}
```